# Chapter outline numbers as initials in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, odt, koffice

I am trying to have the chapter title (outline) level 1 numbers as initials in LibreOffice Writer.

I have set up a character style which gives me the big title numbers, but they are all from the base line upwards (most of the numbers are over the letters in the title line).

I do not need a drop cap (text flowing under the number), the number can be all to the left of the title.

I am looking for a solution in LibreOffice, but any word processor working with ODTs would be OK.  In last case, MS Word or anything producing DOCs.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you added a picture of exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: ![This is the first page of such a document](http://dutra.fastmail.fm/termo_refer%C3%AAncia_completo_v3_p1.pdf).  It currently consists of two columns, the first being very narrow and containing only the numbers.  Editing it becomes very cumbersome.

What I aim for is making these numbers into automatic numeration, ideally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it will be very difficult (seeing your example) to work with the normal "Automatic numbering". It can be done with some effort but there are serious drawbacks. You can't use the space below the first line of text because your number is big. You can only put a frame there. Also with every <kbd>enter</kbd> you do, there is a new number created.

Your best bet would be to use linked-frames with numbers.

Set a comfortable margin for your document (enough for the numbers). Set your cursor on the first line and choose `Insert`, `Frame` and set the properties:

[image: Frame properties]

Also set the borderlines/Linestyle to `None`. After that set a big number `1` in the frame and drag the frame left of the margin (before the paragraph). Make sure the anchor stays on the first letter of your line. In the properties of the frame the `Horizontal by` will be negative.

[image: Anchor]

Selecting the frame you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and going to the next line and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to copy a frame there. Change the numbers accordingly.

Now these frames (which are left of the margin) are linked to the first character of your chosen lines and they will flow with it.

Instead of setting a big number in the frame you could set `Numbering On` and adding a space. When copying the frames the frame will number automatically. But you need to see if this is convenient. Adding a number between two others will result in the numbers not being sequential. I think numbering manually is easiest in this situation.

[image: Result]

---

## Edit: I found another method of autonumbering:

You can use this with the linked frames but you can also make a table without borders e.g. 6x2, whichever you find easier, for example below i used a table. A table might be handier when inserting a new section.

Instead of typing the 1, 2 etc you choose `Insert`, `Fields`, `Other` (or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), Choose `Variables` and `Number Range` and in `Name` type `Nr1` and a value of `1` and press <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

[image: Number range]

**Now close the dialog** and goto the second row. Open the dialog again (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) **choose `Nr1` from `Selections`** and press Insert. (The Value is empty in this dialog but because it's a `number range` it will automatically take `last value +1`.

Now you can copy the numbers from row 2 to the other rows or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and choose `Nr1` again. (**Don't** copy it **from row 1** because that has value `1` set, and not `+1`)

The result should be like this: (You can switch between numbers and hidden variable with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> and whenever you insert a row you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to insert the number, **it will keep the numbers sequential**, also when inserting a row.) Of course you can make the numbers bigger.

[image: Result]

And after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> and making the numbers bigger:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not knew about this frame function.

Given I would loose the automatic numbering, I guess I will try to see if I can change the layout of the document, even if it means to have either the item number in the same size of the paragraph or having it extend upwards.

Or, given in this particular case the model is more or less fixed, and quite fixed when it comes to numbering, I could just number manually and use initials.

Comment: Pfew... (that's a lot of images :) I added another method where you **can** use autonumbering. It may be easier to use tables (without borders) instead of linked frames (table-rows are easier to insert between existing rows). But you can use this method of autonumbering with both a table and the linked frame method.

Comment: I am truly impressed.

Comment: I edited my edit slightly. It seems you can do this with one variable (and don't need the `Nr1_next`) When `Nr1` is a `number range` it will automatically increase by one every time it's used (just don't **copy** it from the first row/cell because that has `1` set instead of `+1`, you can see this if you double click on it). I'm learning a lot about LibreOffice too :)

Comment: You are sure a fast learner!